# What's the equivalent of this statement in swift?

Tags: swift, copy

```
id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];  // Objective-C

// ??? in siwft
```

What's the counterpart in swift?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class foo {
    var bar: Int
    required init() {
        bar = 42
    }
}
var a = foo()
var copy = a.dynamicType()
```

Comment: How could I implement NSCopying protocol in UIView with swift?